# Creating usr/local/bin symlinks for things in usr/bin good idea?

Tags: linux, symbolic-link

I have a Linux production server and development machine that runs OSX. Stuff that is in usr/local/bin on development is installed into usr/bin on Linux. That creates some problems and I always have to modify the values in some scripts by hand on , so that they reflect the situation on production server.. I thought maybe I can just create symlinks for things in usr/bin in usr/local/bin on production and solve my issue?

Comment: Paths should not be hard-coded. The program could as well be installed into `/home/me/bin` if installed with user rights, into `/usr/bin` if packaged and installed with the distributions package manager or to `/usr/local/bin` if that's the local policy.

Comment: thanks, for some reason the bash scripts did not respond unless I am using full paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I heard a lot of bad things about the autoconf tools. Mostly due to the lack of documentation and lot lot of copy and paste programming. But it this sounds like it is the perfect tool for this job.

Basically it allows you do check for programs, libraries etc. If a suitable target is not found then it can switch to an alternative. This would make your setup much more flexible.

If you do not care about flexibility then go ahead and create softlinks with `ln -s`.  (If you use a hard link and one copy of the software gets updated then you could end up with two installed versions),